# Is it possible to use the "allDaySlot" option with TimelineView fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I would like to use the all day option with my Timeline View calendar but the row is not showing up. I am using fullcalendar with vuejs.

Is it even possible to have the AllDay option with timeline calendar like this ?
[image]

If not, what can i do to have a special single first row resource ? (like allDay)

### UPDATE:

I remove my rooms event and i only put this simple allDay event:

```js
events: [{
            id: 'a',
            title: 'event 1',
            start: '2020-06-23',
            allDay: true
        }]
```

My view looks like this:

[image]

I have a custom 3 month timeline and as you can see nothing appears on it. I didn't set the allDaySlot to *true* because the documentation says it is enabled by default.

### UPDATE

Is something like this possible ? (green: resources | gray: headers)

[image]

Comment: All-day events should still show up in the timeline. Please show your code and event data

Comment: P.s. "special single first row resource" makes no sense because the time goes horizontally in this view, not vertically. Did you mean an all-day _column_?

Comment: My resources are Room (with the number and the category the room belong to). I would like to have an *all-day* row just  under the day headers so i could put special kind of events (conferences, festive events ...)

Comment: If you want to have that you should just add another resource. Then give the events in that resource appropriate start and end dates and they'll show up with the correct width on the calendar, according to the horizontal time axis. An "all-day" _row_ still makes no sense - "all-day" isn't a resource, it's a time period, and the times are shown horizontally, so anything representing a period of time like "all-day" would need to be a _column_ (the inverse of the timeGrid example where the time axis is vertical).

Comment: Okay but the problem is that my special events have nothing to do with the *Nummer* and *Kategorie* header. Is there any proper way to have resources header one above the other ? So i could have a *Special events* header, then my single resource, then my *Nummer* and *Kategorie* header and then my rooms resources

Comment: No, there's no way to do that with fullCalendar currently. You'd have to fork the source code for the timeline view and make a custom version of it which is capable of rendering in that way. But that's potentially quite a large job.

Comment: This is about the closest you can get with the built-in functionality, I think: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/pogqqEq